# Linux interface bonding with ifenslave

Tags: debian, nic

I have a little project that i'm working on under a virtual machine. I'm learning to bond interfaces for redundancy and what not but i had one question that i have not been able to find on google quite easily...

When i set up my `bond0` to `bond-mode 0` which is round robin, i installed and ran `bwm-ng` to monitor the traffic going through each interface and noticed that the outgoing traffic is split between the two interfaces `eth0` being the primary interface and slave 1, `eth1` being slave 2. What i noticed is that all the returning traffic returns through `eth0` the primary interface which makes sense but the question that raised in my mind is - is there a way to get incoming traffic to go through both interfaces at the same time? as in possibly force both `eth0` and `eth1` as primaries?

i did try this and the config is as follows:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-mode 0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 400
    bond-updelay 800
```

but the incoming traffic seems to still come in `eth0` opposed to what i thought would happen, just like the outgoing traffic gets split then maybe the incoming traffic would split as well. Nope.

Any ideas?

If my explanation is a bit hard to understand, please let me know and ill try to rephrase it as best as i can!

Comment: could it be a limitation of the (virtual) switch you're connected to?

Comment: the interfaces on the VM are bridged, so they're connected to the router/switch i'm using at the moment which is a Linksys with DD-WRT firmware. However my actual router is a raspberry-pi i set up with nat. i built my own wifi extender in other words. but yea...

Comment: Also, im using virtualbox and each adapter has Promiscuous mode to deny. i dont think that would affect my goal but im just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 0):

On your virtual machine you can only decide the algorithm for outgoing traffic.  Incoming traffic is decided by the switch on the other end.

In your case it looks as if you would need to configure bonding on the Linksys.

If your vm host is using the same physical interfaces as the vm, beware that if you configure bonding on the Linksys you will need to configure bonding on the vm host as well.